# How to get an access to the views through ViewpageAdapter?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

This is my first time with ViewPager and after some time it now works, that I can switch between three different Activities (Main, Scan, and Options). My problem is to get access to the listViews, EditText and the FloatingActionButton inside the Main- and ScanActivity.

What I want to achieve, should be similar to this:

```
private FloatingActionButton fab;
public static void setupContent (View view, String title) {
......
fab = view.findViewById (R.id.fab);
....
}
public void someMethod () {
fab.setOnClickListener....
}
```

For references beyond the code below, check my github: https://github.com/ChristopherPS96/SmartFridge/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/christopher/smartfridge 
Beware that this project is work in progress, so not everything is perfect

This is the method inside the MainActivity.java, which works. Now I want to expand it, that I can set OnClickTimeListener on my ListView or do anything with anything outside of this method for that matter. Always I get NullpointerExceptions or nothing happens at all.

```
public static void setupContent(View view, String title) {
    if(title.equals("Hauptseite")) {
        FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
    if(title.equals("Scanseite")) {
        FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fabScan);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Alternativer Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What I have tried so far:

-making the ListView, EditText static (which causes NullpointerException and a MemoryLeak) 
-storing the view and title inside of an static ArrayList (ArrayList is empty) 
-calling a new method with MainActivity mainactivity = new MainActivity() 
mainactivity.someMethod() (NullpointerException)

Comment: Can you be more clear on what you are trying to achieve? Also, ScanActivity class does not exist on your GitHub link.

Comment: The FloatingActionButton, ListView etc. only work inside the method above (which is in my MainActivity.java). I want to use them in the whole MainActivity. I mean the three layouts maincontent, scanitem, setting (sry I always call them ScanActivity etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @yupi. It will be much simpler to have 3 fragments instead of 3 activities. "You will be able to maintain code in future".

After setting this code in your Home activity, you will have to create fragment classes for (SettingFragment, ScanItemFragment, and MainContentFragment). You can move your existing layout from the already existing activities to your fragment's layout. You will have to make few modifications due to the differences of lifecycle between activities and fragments, but it should not take you too much time.

*This code should totally get you started with what you trying to achieve. Good Luck !*

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionPageAdapter mSectionPageAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        // Create the adapter that returns a fragment for each tab
        mSectionPageAdapter = new SectionPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        //Set up the view pager with different section adapters
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.contentFrameLayout);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionPageAdapter);
        mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);

        //Set up the tab layout to display tabs
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.homeTabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    //add icons to tabs and change the text behavior
    for (int i = 0; i< tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {

        TabLayout.Tab mTab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        if (mTab != null) {
            switch (i){
                case 0:
                    mTab.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_zero);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mTab.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_one);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mTab.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_two);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}


/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the tabs.
 */
private class SectionPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    SectionPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return (MainContentFragment.newInstance());
            case 1:
                return (ScanItemFragment.newInstance());
            case 2:
                return (SettingFragment.newInstance());
            default:
                break;
        }

            return (null);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Ok, it seems like I dont get around Fragments. So let say I get it to work with Fragments, where is the differnence? How or Where do I get my ListView, EditText etc then?

Comment: I think i got my own answer. For each layout I make a Fragment and over this Fragment I get access to TextView etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually doing right now is switching between different layouts. Probably what you want is to create three `Fragments` with each layout you have right now. Than create adapter extending `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and inside `getItem` according to `position` return corresponding `Fragment`. Than set your adapter to `ViewPager` and now you will be able to swipe and to access views in `Fragments`.

Comment: I have read about the fragments, but never used them, so I hoped it would work without them, because it looked somewhere hard to learn. For me this would be my last choice.

Comment: I didn't take a look deeply inside your code but I don't think that is even possible what you are trying right now and if it is I'm afraid it will be much harder to accomplish that and maintain code in future.